# Change a specific pathname with new browser URL or history replaceState

Tags: javascript, jquery

My url is similar to this

```
https://example.com/en/login
```

Considering that the the locale will always be there, how can I change that specific path

This has to happen inside the change of the select

```
    $("#lang").on("change", async function (e) {
        alert(window.location.pathname.split("/")[2]);
        Cookies.set("lang", $(this).val(), { expires: 30 });
        window.location.reload(false);
    });
```

before the page reloads

Comment: You have a drop-down list with the list of languages ​​and when you change your language you want, generate a new URL to use to reload the page is that...?

Comment: I could generate a new url or just change that locale path

Answer (score 2):

Get `document.location.pathname` split it by `/` replace the token you want and join it back to string. And update browser's URL:

```
$("#lang").on("change", async function (e) {
    const arr = document.location.pathname.split("/");
    arr[2] = this.value;
    history.replaceState(undefined, '', arr.join("/"));
});
```